# Change the look 2013

Tags: sharepoint

I have recently been introduced to Sharepoint 2013, i have used the sharepoint palette download to change set colours in an .spcolor file. I have uploaded these and all worked fine however I now dont seem to be able to change the look it just hangs and when clicking Try this out i get an error message.

I am using Oslo if that makes difference.

I even tried just altered the .spcolor file and replaced it in the Themes folder 15. When I go to change the look the current theme shows the updates in the small preview thumbnail however the page does not.

Does anyone know if this error is becasue ive uploaded my own .spcolor?

Thanks in advance
Helen

Answer (score 1):

We found an issue with this when the name of the spcolor file contained an underscore.

With it there the theme could be previewed but not applied. When we renamed the file it worked fine. This issue may apply to all special characters in the spcolor filename.